# insall SOAPpy using pip

Tags: python, django, installation, pip, soappy

I want to install SOAPpy library on my windows 7 but when I run "pip install soappy" or "easy_install soappy" I get this error: "ImportError: No module named WSDLTools"
also I try download zip file and compile and install it but again I get this error. anyone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use Python2? SOAPpy isn't compatible with Python3.

Comment: no I am using python 3.2, so what soap library I can use ?

Comment: @user2141833 I used to use SUDS. It is simple and has nice API.